Resource-editor in VS not allowing me to add a resource. "Must have at least one group..."
Using Visual Studio 17.12.3 on Windows 11 desktop. When I select project...properties...resources...create or open assembly resources" and click the "+" sign I receive an error message saying "Must have at least one group. Parameter name: groups." This is on a new windows desktop project using vb.net. Does anyone have an idea what's going on? 

Finally figured it out ... didn't realize that I needed to first add a resource file in the resources view window.
Thanks all!
